# Can a typescript function output 2 different data types?

Tags: typescript

I have a function that could either output a string or undefined value. I've currently separated either output with the | operator. Is this correct, or is there a better way?

```js
export function retrievePath(specFile: any): string | undefined{
  // ...
};
```

Comment: This is correct. But you should probably type `specFile` as something else than `any`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct.

In another way, you can define a `type` of `string | undefined`.

```js
type PathType = string | undefined;

export function retrievePath(specFile: any): PathType {
  // ...
}
```